# .NET MVC Modal Form Submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, bootstrap-modal

Just a general question regarding submitting forms within a modal and the associated Action.

I have an existing standard form that scaffolding creates for you which uses the "Cases/CreateCase" action. This action would save the form and has a standard Redirect To Action to return Index.cshtml

I want to allow the user to do a shortened "Quick Case" version of this case form from the home page.

I have updated the Home/Index.cshtml to include a button which will open a modal  (modal id = "createCaseModalForm") which contains a form for "Cases/CreateQuickCase" action. This is currently an ActionResult.

This uses similar logic to the previous "Cases/CreateCase" action, but this time rather than have a re-direct action for submission I simply want for the data to be saved and the modal to close.  ID of the form is "#createQuickCaseForm"

Do I need ajax for this modal submission?

What should the Controller action return, since it has to return something. And should it be a different action type  other than an "Action Result"??

Thanks

Comment: If I understood correctly, it's more simple than it looks. You don't need an ajax, just post the form normally but do it on Save button of modal dialog.

Comment: You can create partial view with your form and then use it in view and in modal, and as @derloopkat said, just submit form and result will be the same.

Comment: Sorry I didn't meant to be as vague. It's literally the controller action I dunno what it should be doing. I have the partial view in modal and I know how to attach the closing of the modal to the submit button. It's more what the controller action should be doing. Should it be an action result? And I have the logic to validate and save the data but what should the action return if its a successful submission. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question correctly then you want to achieve two goals.

1. To save data on submit
2. To close the modal on submit

To achieve this you can call the normal controller action and also write a jquery which will help you to close modal when submit button clicked.

JQuery code can be like:
$('#YourSubmitButtonID').click(CLOSEMODAL)

Comment: Thanks that is half the battle. What should the controller Action be? Or what should it return - since I don't want to return View(page refresh) or get re-directed anywhere else what should the controller do after it saves the data? Thanks

Comment: return View() doesn't actually refresh the page. So you can write that and check.